# How to hide please use the correct version resource dll dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging

I changed image inside dll after that when i run the app i'm getting 1 dialog like below

[image]

Any one please tell me how to ignore or hide this dialog from user ?
i thing this is Microsoft VisualStudio debugger dialog(
Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.WpfVisualTreeService.Adorners.AdornerLayerWindow).

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-standard message (the only google hits are to this page), so it sounds like the program you are running (which you don't tell us), is doing some sort of check to work out if a dll it is using has been modified.  This could be a size check, or a CRC check, or simply a date check.

If you want to disable this check, you could either work out WHERE the program is doing the check and bypass the code, or you could work out HOW the program is doing the check and fix the dll so that is passes the check.

Either way, would involve de-compiling the code (much easier since this is C#). 
 You could then patch the `if` so that the message is not shown, or modify the code that checks for the changed dll.